# Validation of a command line parameter in WiX

Tags: wix

I want to validate the value of a command line property in WiX given by the user during installation. If the value of the property is not one among the specific set, it should take a default value and create a registry entry.

For example, property USERLEVEL should have value 1-4. If user specifies any other value it should default to 1 and write it to the registry. The installer does not have a UI component and we want to do this using some conditional statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **SetProperty** element to change the USERLEVEL property value. You can use the (USERLEVEL<1 OR USERLEVEL>4) Condition to check the value, but it won’t work if end user pass any non-integer value like ‘A’.

```
<Property Id="USERLEVEL" Secure="yes" />

<SetProperty Id="USERLEVEL" Value="1" After="AppSearch">
    USERLEVEL&lt;&gt;1 AND USERLEVEL&lt;&gt;2 AND USERLEVEL&lt;&gt;3 AND USERLEVEL&lt;&gt;4
</SetProperty>
```

You can use the below code to write the property into registry.

```
<Component Id="CMP_UserLevel" Guid="{FD70BBE3-F7F1-460E-AA7C-56750F66536D}">
      <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Sample, Inc.\Test Installer">
          <RegistryValue Name="USERLEVEL" Value="[USERLEVEL]" Type="integer" />
      </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

Answer (score 2):

That can be done easiest with a "Launch Condition". As a child of `Product` element add a `Condition` element with a message. For example:

```
<Product ...>
   ...

   <Condition Message='The USERLEVEL property has an invalid value of: [USERLEVEL]. Please ensure the value falls in the range of 1 to 4.'>
      USERLEVEL&gt;0 AND USERLEVEL&lt;5
   </Condition>
```

I used the `&gt;` and `&lt;` rather than wrapping the condition in `CDATA` but you can do it however you like.  The end result is that you want the condition to say something like `USERLEVEL > 0 and USERLEVEL < 5` (or if you prefer: `USERLEVEL >=1 AND USERLEVEL <= 4`).

Comment: is there a way to check the length of the provided string? i.e. if I want to enforce strings only of a specific length or longer than some certain number of characters provided from a command line?