# How can I produce an error for unexpected command line parameters in WIX?

Tags: .net, wix, windows-services, windows-installer

I am using WiX/WixSharp to produce an MSI for a windows service I am writing.

The MSI should have one custom property CONFIGPATH which can be used to specify the path of the configuration file to be used by the service.

I have this represented in the ServiceInstall element:

```
<ServiceInstall ... Arguments="[CONFIGPATH]">
```

While this works, what I have noticed is that my installer will also accept any other parameters you might pass and will silently ignore them, for example you can run:

```
msiexec -i MyInstaller.msi CONFIGPATH=config.json FAKEPROPERTY=random
```

This runs without error, which could make troubleshooting difficult. My question is whether there is a method within WiX to perform such validation?

I looked at [Validation of a command line parameter in WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253897/validation-of-a-command-line-parameter-in-wix) but this only gave an approach for validating one parameter, not the full list.

Comment: Using a custom action you can inspect any value specified in an incoming property. Specified properties that have no relevance for the setup's operation can be safely ignored? However, you can make the setup check the validity of the path if you really want to. I prefer to inspect logging instead since custom actions are new sources of potential bugs. Some samples here: [WiXCustomActionsTesting.zip](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all)

Comment: @SteinÅsmul can you point me to a specific file in that solution that shows where this is happening? I'm not super familiar with WiX generally so I don't know what kind of logic you can embed into custom actions or whether that would work with WixSharp.